# My command prompt is downloading bottle web framework but not installing and showing error

Tags: command-line

[image: enter image description]

command prompt is downloading the packages but while installation it is showing error

Comment: Please copy/paste the transcript as text, not as images.  Site indexers won't find the error message inside the image, people who want to help will have to jump through hoops to transcribe your problem correctly, etc.  See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Try using command as administrator. It could work as it is showing an error related to permissions.